# Why is replacing Javascript inline functions with function calls producing different behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have 2 functions to show and clear a window. Originally I had them defined inline with the jquery hover command, as in `$('item').hover(function() {...}, function() {...});` and this works perfectly. However if I take the code from those function calls and isolate them to call it like `$('item').hover(function1, function2);`, the result is different. In the former case I get the expected behavior. That is, on hover the element shows, and after a timeout fades out if the mouse stays off the hover'd element. In the second version, the new element shows, fades out after the timeout, and doesn't come back on hover.

I'm assuming that it has something to do with the timeouts I'm using, but I copied the functions exactly from the original, so theoretically it should be the same stuff happening.. or so I would naively assume. Either that or I made a typo somewhere that I'm just not catching.

Fiddles with full code and html are available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NmTHd/2/) (working version) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NmTHd/1/) (broken version).

Here's the code for the one that works:

```
$('#test').hide();
var timeout;

$('a').hover(function(){
    $('#test').show();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}, function(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#test').fadeOut('fast', function(){});
    }, 1000);
});
```

And here's what fails:

```
$('#test').hide();
var timeout;

function clearWindow() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#test').fadeOut('fast', function(){});
    }, 1000);
}

function showWindow() {
    $('#test').show();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

$('a').hover(showWindow(), clearWindow());
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parentheses when passing the functions to `.hover()`.

```
$('a').hover(showWindow, clearWindow);
```

The parentheses invoke the functions, which means that you're passing the value *returned* by calling `showWindow()`/`clearWindow()` rather than the functions themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the functions when you meant to pass them:

```
$('a').hover(showWindow(), clearWindow());
                       ^^             ^^
```

Use this instead (you want to pass the functions themselves, not the (`undefined`) values they return):

```
$('a').hover(showWindow, clearWindow);
```

Note that in general, it *is* possible to have code that has been moved to a different function behave differently, since it may reference a different set of contextual variables (i.e. be in a different scope than it was originally in). This does not apply to the functions you have here, however.

Comment: And once again I feel dumb.. although relieved that it was something that simple, thank you

Comment: @ssb: No worries, at least it's something simple and easy to fix :-)